# Create and show progressBar with backgroundWorker - VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-c++, progress-bar, backgroundworker

I want show marquee progress bar in another thread of my app.
Here is my code:

```
bkgWorker->RunWorkerAsync();

private: System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar^  progressBar;

private: System::Void bkgWorker_DoWork(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::DoWorkEventArgs^  e) {
    progressBar = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBar());
    progressBar->Location = System::Drawing::Point(548, 349);
    progressBar->MarqueeAnimationSpeed = 15;
    progressBar->Name = L"progressBar";
    progressBar->Size = System::Drawing::Size(100, 23);
    progressBar->Style = System::Windows::Forms::ProgressBarStyle::Marquee;
    progressBar->TabIndex = 23;
    progressBar->Show();
}

private: System::Void bkgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(System::Object^  sender, System::ComponentModel::RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs^  e) {
    progressBar->Hide();
}
```

There is no fault, but I do not see the progress bar on my form.
What am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

there are better and newer solutions replaced the old good background worker.
I suggest you to look at [`async await` design.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) 
Read this post: [Reporting Progress from Async Tasks](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html)

The code should look something like this:

```
public async void StartProcessingButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // The Progress<T> constructor captures our UI context,
  //  so the lambda will be run on the UI thread.
  var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
  {
    textBox1.Text = percent + "%";
  });

  // DoProcessing is run on the thread pool.
  await Task.Run(() => DoProcessing(progress));
  textBox1.Text = "Done!";
}

public void DoProcessing(IProgress<int> progress)
{
  for (int i = 0; i != 100; ++i)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100); // CPU-bound work
    if (progress != null)
      progress.Report(i);
  }
}
```